# How do I extract the token of a Google Service Account?

Tags: api, android-studio, authentication, request, dialogflow-es

I'm using Fuel library on Android Studio to connect a mobile app to Dialogflow and develop a chatbot. I only need the access token.

To follow the steps of using Dialogflow API v2, I read this web page:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

Do you know what command is equivalent to "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"?

Comment: I'm programming in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to generate a service account key file, as specified in the [doc page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup#getting_the_service_account_key). You can use this key file to authenticate using the [Dialogflow Java client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-dialogflow), according to [these instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#authentication).